# How to send user back to login page after session timeout in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring

Right Now I am using following code in web.xml file to invalidate the session.

```
  <session-config>
      <session-timeout>
        10

      </session-timeout>
 </session-config>
```

Comment: Unclear question. Its your application server's duty to do that. It will invalidate the session and when client perform any action it automatically re-direct to login page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Security you can set the url of the login page. i.e

```
    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/home**" access="hasRole('USER')" />
    <security:form-login 
        login-page="/signin" 
        default-target-url="/home" 
        authentication-failure-url="/signin?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/signin" />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <security:csrf/>
```

The **logout-success-url** will be the destination of your application once sessions times out.

**Note**: Client page will not automatically detect the invalidated session from the server if there is no request from client side. You need Ajax calls to achieve this. Maybe this site can help you. [Session Timeout handling for Ajax calls](https://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/04/21/spring-security-part-vi-session-timeout-handling-for-ajax-calls/)